# req.params.id is undefined, I can't figure out why

Tags: node.js

Here is the URL in browser:

```
http://localhost:3001/user/59cc018171149931f4e435ac
```

This is the code for the route:

```
router.get("/new", middleware.userLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    //find user by id
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("characters/addCharacter", {user: foundUser});
        }
    });
});
```

This is the middleware:

```
middlewareObj.userLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
    // eval(require('locus'));
    if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.params.id.equals(req.user._id)) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
};`
```

When I run the app everything works fine. Expect the request on the route above, which giving me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'equals' of undefined". When I take off the middleware and try to console.log(req.params.id), it returns "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I have my route configured in app.js:

```
app.use("/user/:id/characters", characterRoutes);
```

So the ":id" is there.
When I use `/new/:id` instead of `/new` getting new error message:

> "Cannot GET /user/59c23b864262fc2c186677be/characters/new"

Answer (score 2):

use `/new/:id` instead of `/new`

```
router.get("/new/:id", middleware.userLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    //find user by id
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, foundUser){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("characters/addCharacter", {user: foundUser});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the parameter you want in your path, like so `/new/:id` and then you can use `req.params.id` in your code.

Here's the Express documentation for this [part](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#req)

Comment: I get another error then. I forgot to mention that I have my routes set up in app.js I have edited the post.

Comment: I have edited, this time successfuly. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

cast req.params into any first:

let params: any = req.params

and then params.id should work

Answer (score 0):

This thread talks about needing to define the param in the `.use(...)`
For example:

`app.use('/:param1', (err, req, res, next) => ...)`

https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4298